# Applying "which.max" or any other function to every cell in a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have tried all the suggestions available online but none leads to the desired result.

Here is my code:

```r
usualviterbi <- function(x, Pi, delta, emission) {
  n <- length(x)
  m <- nrow(Pi)
  nu <- log(matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = m))
  phi <-  matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = m) 
  y <- rep(NA, n)
  #Initialisation
  nu[1, ] <- log(delta) + log(emission[1,])
  ########

  #Recursion
  if (n>1) {
    logPi <- log(Pi)
    for (i in 2:n) {
      matrixnu <- matrix(nu[i - 1, ], nrow = m, ncol = m)
      nu[i, ] <- apply(matrixnu + logPi, 2, max) + log(emission[i,])
      #phi[i,]= which.max(nu[i, ]) - log(emission[i,]) ###
      phi[i,]= apply(nu[,i, drop=FALSE] - log(emission[,i,drop=FALSE]) , c(1,2), which.max)
      #phi[i,]= data.frame(lapply(nu[i,] - log(emission[i,]), which.max))
    }
    #phi= apply(nu - log(emission), c(1,2), which.max)
    ########

    #Termination
    y[n] <- which.max(nu[n,])      #final phi
    final_nu <- max(nu[n,])     #final delta
    ######## 
    #Backtracking  
    for (i in seq(n - 1, 1, -1)) {  
      y[i] <- which.max(logPi[, y[i + 1]] + nu[i, ])
    }
  } else {
    y <- which.max(nu[n,])
  }   #termination 
  return(phi); 
  #return(nu); 
  #return(y)
}

x <- c(1,2,3,1)
Pi <- matrix(c(0.4,0.6,0.7,0.3),nrow=2, byrow=T)
delta <- c(0.2,0.8)
emission <- matrix(c(0.1,0.2,0,0.8,0.9,0,0.1,0.2), nrow=length(x), ncol=2, byrow=T)
usualviterbi(x, Pi, delta, emission)
```

As an output I want a 4*2 `phi` matrix that would return a `which.max` function applied to each cell in `nu` matrix. In the recursion block of my code you can see some of my attempts but they all lead to errors incl. the need of the positive dim length (usual error with `apply` f.).

Comment: I see no *recursion* in this code, that would typically involve calling `usualviterbi` from within `usualviterbi` with slightly-different arguments.

Comment: There are many overly complicated lines in this code (e.g. `log(matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = m))` is just ` matrix(-Inf, nrow = n, ncol = m)`,  or if you switch the order `log(phi)`,  etc. Also, the code block you are commenting as 'Recursion' has no recursion in it, and assumes `n` == `m` which is probabl the reason for the error.